# for loop twice or any alternate ways so that I print only the first loop element but get the values from second loop

Tags: python

I have two lists...........

```
a = [["My inner first"], ["My inner second", "My inner third"]] <br>
b = [["technical"], ["little messy", "something"]]
```

When I use for loop to loop this way:

```
for x in a:
    for xx in x:
        for xxx in b:
            for xxxx in xxx:
                print(xx)
```

or

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for x in a[i]:
        for xx in b[i]:
            print(x, xx)
```

My expected output should be:

```
My inner first technical <br>
My inner second little messy<br>
My inner third something messy<br>
```

However my actual output became:

```
My inner first technical <br>
My inner first little messy <br>
My inner first something <br>
My inner second technical <br>
My inner second little messy <br>
My inner second something <br>
My inner third technical <br>
My inner third little messy <br>
My inner third something <br>
```

or

```
My inner first technical <br>
My inner second little messy <br>
My inner second something <br> 
My inner third little messy <br> 
My inner third something <br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
a = [["My inner first"], ["My inner second", "My inner third"]]
b = [["technical"], ["little messy", "something"]]

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        print(a[i][j], b[i][j])
```

> Outputs:
>
> My inner first technical
>
> My inner second little messy
>
> My inner third something

Comment: Thank you sir. This is what I wanted it to be

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip`

**Ex:**

```
a = [["My inner first"], ["My inner second", "My inner third"]] 
b = [["technical"], ["little messy", "something"]]

for i, v in zip(a, b):
    for j, k in zip(i, v):
        print(j, k)
```

**Output:**

```
My inner first technical
My inner second little messy
My inner third something
```